# Space between tabs in Android

Tags: android, tabs

I have space between my tabs. I looked at all the possible solutions on StackOverflow and added them but still the space exists between them.

My tab code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

My Layout with tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_image"
        android:dividerPadding="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:showDividers="none"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </TabWidget>
   </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

I added the following in code as well:

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(false);
mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(LinearLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
}
```

But still it shows space between tabs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I have not got chances to check these from the android IDE. but I suppose this would work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20.0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20.0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20.0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20.0" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20.0" />
</FrameLayout>

<TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_image"
    android:dividerPadding="0dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:showDividers="none"
    android:tabStripEnabled="false"
    android:visibility="visible" >
</TabWidget>
```

Here, I have gave a weightSum = 100.0 and divided this equivalently to all the childs.

Comment: If I do not add android:layout_weight="20" in tabcontent FrameLayout it does not show tabs.